# Precious Stone, as Clear as Diamond

Tags: riddle

A precious stone, as clear as diamond. 
Seek it out while the sun's near the horizon. 
Though you can walk on water with its power, 
try to keep it, and it'll vanish within the hour.

What is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **ice**.

A precious stone, as clear as diamond.

> Ice is transparent.

Seek it out while the sun's near the horizon.

> Ice appears in the winter, when the Sun is on average lower in the sky than in the summer.

Though you can walk on water with its power,

> You can walk on frozen water.

try to keep it, and it'll vanish within the hour.

> Because it melts in your hand.

Comment: Another fast answer, good job!